Screensharing not appearing in safari
I have made a simple web application that where you can share your screen. link is here. I can stream a screen on my computer to my iphone 13. However, I cannot stream a tab on my iphone to my computer. Why is this?What am I doing wrong?Thank you!
I was expecting it to work when streaming a screen on my phone to my computer.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
